# Python Can't load background images in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i try to load backgroud.png using pygame.image.load(),but i get nothing.here is my code,please help me ,thanks.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 700))

# 1.load_image
bg = pygame.image.load("./images/background.png")

# 2.blit 
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

# 3.update
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    pass

pygame.quit()
```

here is my sreen:[it get nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKbHY.png)

Comment: thanks very much, i found my problem, and it works.*-*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a game you're making all stuff that needs to be refreshed needs to be in the main game loop, your problem is, is you are drawing the image outside that game loop, meaning it gets drawn once then cleared and never drawn again.

To fix your code this is how you would write it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 700))

# 1.load_image
bg = pygame.image.load("./images/background.png")



while True:
    # 2.blit 
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    # 3.update
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

But notice how the `bg=pygame.image...` is outside the loop, this is because if it was inside the loop it would create a new instance of that image every time the loop happens.

The main game loop works by looping through all your functions and other stuff and then doing again and again, and again.

A game loop is how `fps` works, basically it is the measurement of how many times per second that game loop happens.
Make sure whenever you are doing anything in the loop it actually has a place there, for example loading an image doesn't, but updating where the player is on the screen does.

If you want to have a look at a good game loop that can be applied to most game engines this website will help you. But don't look at the most complex one when using pygame as it isn't built for that.  [Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)

But your original problem of the image not loading isn't the case, it was loading but you were drawing your image in the wrong way, if you want a basic tutorial on pygame watch these videos: [Game Development in Python 3 With PyGame - 1 - Intro](https://youtu.be/ujOTNg17LjI)

---

### A better system to ease development

```
import pygame

bg = None

def load_resources():
    bg = pygame.image.load("./images/background.png")
    # all other resources

def render():
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))

def update():
    # all logic updates for example movement of entities.

### start of game

load_resources()

while True:
    update()
    render()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: your example as is will use 100% CPU in a crazy loop - you might want to include a small pause there.

Also, maybe the `update` will continue not to work due to stalled events- this varies with the host O.S. - a call to `pygame.event.pump()` and using `pygame.display.flip()` will ensure the updating.

Comment: @jsbueno yes, I forgot about that because I haven't done anything with pygame for a long time so I completely forgot about a pausing system.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should  not write pass inside while loop because of it the output window will stop responding. Also you should write the screen blit and  display.update inside while loop and you should write the correct image extension in the path. You can also write the full path of the file like ==> pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\Desktop\back_ground.jpg")

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 700))

# 1.load_image
bg = pygame.image.load("back_ground.jpg")



while True:
    # 2.blit 
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    # 3.update
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Comment: Welcom!! @DaMeilao